# Any way to subvert class redeclaration issue? No namespaces

Tags: php, class

Heads up: I dont have the possibility to rename the classes or use name spaces for this.

Im looking for any crazy way to subvert class redeclaration issues in php. I actually only need 3 static variables from a web application, but the only way to get them requires including a file that declares a user class. However I already have a user class, so I get an error.

I tried to no avail to include the file in a class hoping it would isolate the included file - But no.

I tried reading an interface file I created that just echos the 3 values, but that actually just reads the php code and not the rendered values.

Is there anything like an opto-isolation system for code?

The only think I can think of is using ajax to do it, but it seems super sketchy. Is there a plain php version of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Was a comment, but got too long.) Doesn't sound doable with your constraints. (You might need to show some code.) -- But if you are asking for a crazy way, and the option to rename the classes just applies to not editing the php script, then:

Load the include file into a variable, then transform it, and finally eval:

```
$source = file_get_contents("user.php");
$source = str_replace("class user", "class workaround_123", $source);
eval($source); // will give you a workaround_user instead of class conflict
```

Someone will probably comment on the advisability of eval... But it foremost depends on your code/situation if that's an applicable wacky workaround.

Alternatively you could invoke the user fetching code with a separate PHP process :

```
exec("QUERY_STRING=user=123 php-cgi user.php");
```

Comment: OH man! Sooooo close! exec works perfectly. But the user class uses session data, and since exec uses the server to access the file, the session is that of the server, and not me. Thank you. I think this is as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could [tokenize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) the whole file and go through it "by hand" to find the values you need.